# How to make a cookie save and get system?

Tags: php

I am making a system that saves someone's UDID (iOS) and outputs it back in the original input field.

It is for an iOS web-app I am working on. I have tried this:

```
<?php
    $udid = $_POST['udid'];
    if(empty($udid)){
        $udid = $_COOKIE['udid'];
    } else {
        $udid = $_POST['udid'];
    }
?>
<form class='form-horizontal well' action='#' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='udid' class='input-large' placeholder="udid" value='<?php $udid ?>'>
    <button type='submit' id='submit' class='badge-primary'>Save</button>
</form>
<?php
    setcookie("udid", $udid, time()+31536000000, "/");
?>
```

I need the user's udid to be saved and then outputted in the input field. When I ran this, the UDID didn't display in the input field. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Change this `<?php $udid ?>` to `<?= $udid; ?>`

Comment: ``<?php echo $udid ?>`` in your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you error is on the line below:

```
<input type='text' name='udid' class='input-large' placeholder="udid" value='<?php $udid ?>'>
```

Change it to:

```
<input type='text' name='udid' class='input-large' placeholder="udid" value='<?= $udid ?>'>
```

Notice I changed: `<?php $udid ?> to <?= $udid ?>`

This way your PHP script will echo the variable.

In fact, `<?=` is just a shorthand for `<?php echo` since php5.4

Comment: Thank you. I will test to see if this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `echo` the variable `$udid`

```
value='<?php echo $udid ?>'
```

Make sure the variable `$udid` not empty else the cookie never assigned.